# Laravel undefined variable but it is

Tags: laravel, database, variables, routes, undefined

I have a problem "Undefined variable $medzisklads",  this is code of my print from databases, variable $medzisklads is undefined but I have defined in MedziskladController in index.I have 3 Models Sklad, Medzisklad and Vydajsklad. And I used this same code for Sklad with change variables, which I use for Sklad and it works. But for Medzisklad and Vydajsklad dont work and show me error with undefined variable. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2P5q.png)

This is my foreach in index.blade.php.

```
 @foreach($medzisklads as $medzisklad)
   <br>
        {{$medzisklad->medzidatle}} {{$medzisklad->medzimandle}} {{$medzisklad->medzimarcipan}} {{$medzisklad->medziorechy}}
           
   @endforeach
```

and this is my MedziskladController

```
public function index()
{
    $medzisklads = Medzisklad::all();
   return view('sklads.index')-> with('medzisklads', $medzisklads);
}
```

and this is my route

```
Route::resource('medzisklad', 'App\Http\Controllers\MedziskladController');
```

Medzisklad is model in databases.

Comment: Not sure if that space in `-> with` makes a difference or not. What does `dd($medzisklads);` output from your method?

Comment: I tried dd($medzisklads); but still show me undefined.  I have 3 Models Sklad, Medzisklad and Vydajsklad. And I used this same code for Sklad with change variables, which I use for Sklad and it works. But for Medzisklad and Vydajsklad dont work and show me error with undefined variable. I controlled everything more time but I really dont know where error is.

Comment: What route are you on? Use `dd($medzisklads);` in your _method_ right after `$medzisklads = Medzisklad::all();`. Please [edit] your question and post the _complete_ error message you get (file, line number etc). (And just to be sure, remove the space from `-> with`)

Answer (score 0):

pass array in with the method

```
public function index()
{
   $medzisklads = Medzisklad::get();
   return view('sklads.index')->with(['medzisklads' => $medzisklads]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt work I changed it and still show me undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
   $medzisklads = Medzisklad::get();
   return view('sklads.index', compact('medzisklads'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still same undefined variable. Cant be my route wrong ?

Comment: You need to debug the issue, and check one at a time if the data getting passed properly. first do a dump at the controller before return view, then create a route function and dump there, then dump at view. Also whenever you face this issue try to make a separate route and see if its working or not then colaborate to route::resource.

Comment: Okay I´ll try it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
public function index()
   {
       $medzisklads = Medzisklad::get();
       return view('sklads.index', ['medzisklads'=>$medzisklads]);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but still same. Doesnt work.

Comment: Did you try to print  medzisklads  in controller before sending to view ?

Comment: Not yet i trying now.